# Multiple rows found in information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the primary key column name from PHP script. Here is my sql-

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'applicants' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY'
```

It gives me the following results -

```
 applicant_id
 itemid
 applicantId
 applicantId
```

Currently my primary key is `applicantId`.

How can I get only the current primary key column name?

UPDATE:

The following query solved my problem

```
SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Specify TABLE_SCHEMA also.

Comment: @Akina, an example please.

Comment: An example for what? how to add one more condition into WHERE clause? really?